# Is it possible to setup Guzzle + Pool over HTTP/2?

Tags: php, guzzle, http2

Guzzle provides a mechanism to send concurrent requests: Pool. I used the example from the docs: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests. It works quite fine, sends concurrent requests and everything is awesome except one thing: it seems Guzzle ignores HTTP/2 in this case.

I've prepared a simplified script that sends two requests to https://stackoverflow.com, the first one is using Pool, the second one is just a regular Guzzle request. Only the regular request connects via HTTP/2.

```
<?php

include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client([
    'version' => 2.0,
    'debug' => true
]);

/************************/

$requests = function () {
    yield new Request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com');
};
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests());
$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();

/************************/

$client->get('https://stackoverflow.com', [
    'version' => 2.0,
    'debug' => true,
]);
```

Here is an output: https://pastebin.com/k0HaDWt6 (I highlighted important parts with "!!!!!")

Does anybody know why Guzzle does this and how to make Pool work with HTTP/2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found what was wrong: `new Client()` doesn't actually accept `'version'` as an option if passed to `Pool` requests are created as `new Request()`. Either the protocol version must be provided as an option of every request or the requests must be created as `$client->getAsync()` (or `->postAsync` or whatever).

See the corrected code:

```
...

$client = new Client([
    'debug' => true
]);
$requests = function () {
    yield new Request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com', [], null, '2.0');
};
/* OR
$client = new Client([
    'version' => 2.0,
    'debug' => true
]);
$requests = function () use ($client) {
    yield function () use ($client) {
        return $client->getAsync('https://stackoverflow.com');
    };
};
*/
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests());
$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();

...
```